# State does not change on PrivateRoute Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build private router component for my application.
This is my code.

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={auth:false}    
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let userCheckResult = await checkUser(localStorage.getItem('token'), URL_ENDPOINTS.USER_CHECK);
    if (!isEmptyObj(userCheckResult)) {
      this.setState({auth:true})
    }
  }
  render() {    
    if (this.state.auth) {
      return (
        <Route {...this.rest} {...this.props} component={this.props.component} />
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
      )
    }

  }
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Header />
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/statements" component={Statements} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

In my `componentDidMount` I have updated my state (But it does not change). And I'm trying to refer that state in my render function.

Since It does not change the state.It does not change the route for authenticated users too.

It shows this error on console.

```
index.js:1446 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

If someone can correct my solution it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your state is set to `auth: false` by default. Within your render you instantly redirect if your `this.state.auth` is false. This means the component will always redirect.

You eventually set the state after an async request in the `componentDidMount` but at that point you've already redirected and this component probably has long unmounted by then, thus resulting in the warning of trying to set the state after the component has been unmounted.

To fix this I suggest adding a second variable in your state that keeps track of whether or not you've executed the authentication request. If the authentication has not been executed then in the render you should not redirect yet (maybe show a spinner of some sort). Once it has executed you can determine whether or not the user should be redirected based on the auth.